# Android Stop Runnable created in new Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, udp, runnable

In my `Android` `app` I start a `Runnable` (called `remoteUDPRunnable`) that establishes an `UDP Connection` with another device in a new `Thread`like this:

```
new Thread(remoteUDPRunnable).start();
```

I some cases, I want to stop that `Thread` (and cancel the `UDP connection`) but I don't know how

I'have tried to keep the `Thread` instance in a `variable` and call `myThread.interrupt()` but it doesn't work.

I have also tried using a `Handler` like this:

```
final Handler remoteUDPRunnableHandler = new Handler();
remoteUDPRunnableHandler.post(remoteUDPRunnable);
```

So I can cancel it doing this:

```
remoteUDPRunnableHandler.removeCallbacks(remoteUDPRunnable);
```

That works but when I call the `post(remoteUDPRunnable)` method  I get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. I have also tried to put the code inside the `Runnable` inside an `AsyncTask` but it doesn't work either.

Any ideas? I'm quite new on this and I'm a bit confused about it.
Thanks

Comment: interrupt just sets a flag in the thread. You need to check that flag (Thread.interrupted()) in your Runnable and make sure your thread comes to and end yourself.

Comment: Re, "I'have tried to [...] call `myThread.interrupt()` but it doesn't work.":  Doesn't work how?  That sounds like it would make a good StackOverflow question.  You should make up a small, self-contained example program that other people can run, that shows `t.interrupt()` not doing what you expect it to do; and then you should post it here, and ask us _why_ it doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: P.S.:  There's no reason to use the word "Runnable" in this question.  `Runnable` just means it's an object that has a method named `void run()`.  It doesn't tell us anything about how you are using that object.

Answer (score 2):

If you wrote the the class of `remoteUDPRunnable` yourself, you need to make sure (programmatically) the thread comes to an end.

The call `thread.interrupt()` only sets a flag in that thread. But if you never check it and do something with it, it's completely useless.

In your runnable you need to call `Thread.interrupted()`, if it returns true, initiate the shutdown of the thread. Be careful, the call `Thread.interrupted()` resets the interrupt flag of the executing thread.

Also, if a `InterruptedException` is thrown, the interrupt flag is also reset, so you might need to call `Thread.interrupt()` again in your runnable.